# How does private access specifier works with the provides method in Guice?

Tags: java, guice

```
public class XYZModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    private XYZ provideXYZ() {
        return new XYZ(1, 2);
    }
}
```

I just checked that if I give private or protected or public in provideXYZ(), everything works. Why is it so?

I used to think, when a object of XYZ is required, it would simply call the provideXYZ() but if it is private or protected, how it is able to call? So, I think I am misunderstanding how Guice works.

Any help please.

Comment: Guice works using reflection, and reflection enables to bypass private access. ... At least, if you don't use Java 9+ modules.

Comment: and if there is no `SecurityManager` disallowing access check suppresion

Comment: Even though you can, you shouldn't declare your providers as private. Try to at least declare them with a package-private modifier. This way you can test them with a test framework, should you require it.